# Troubleshooting iis first request response time after recycle

Tags: .net-core, iis-8, azure-vm

We are observing a strange issue on our iis servers: for the same dotnet core project, we are observing very different startup times (response time of first request after recycle)

The servers are azure vm's of size "Standard D11 v2". The configuration should be identical, but of course we can not know for sure if somebody made any manual changes we dont know about.

To measure startup speed, we use the standard asp.net core template project (the one with the weather forecast controller). We deploy this to a new website, and test the performance of the first request after an application pool recycle. On server A, the startup time is about 400 to 500ms. On server B however, this measurement is 10 times higher.

We verified that all configurations in iis manager of site and application pool are identical.

Any ideas how we can effectively troubleshoot this? Are there any diagnostics tools that could help us out?

Comment: You can always get started from failed request tracing.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know, no diagnostics tool for that. But the problem of first request after a while slow can try to fix.

Try the following settings:

- Website application pool -> advanced settings -> General -> Set start mode to "Always Running".
- In IIS Manager, right click on the site for the application, select "Manage Website" -> "Advanced Settings" and set the "Preload Enabled" value to true.